# How do you take a 2D array from a text file, and "copy" it into another array using charAt

Tags: java

I was working through a project and I have to use charAt to continuously add elements of an array from a text file to a new array that i would have specified. The size of the array differs depending on the text file being used so it is best to assume that the contents of the file are unknown, however i will provide an example.

I keep on getting a "StringIndexOutOfBoundException" when i run my code and i am not sure why, or how to fix it.

What the code should be doing is taking the user input to get the exact text file location, then it will be reading that line by line and adding that to a new array. The first two lines of the text file array are the array row and column size.

my code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the location of the board file using the FULL PATH NAME.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n = input.nextLine();
    input.close();

    File a = new File(n); 

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(a);
    int row = sc.nextInt();
    int col = sc.nextInt();

    char[][] board = new char[row][col];

    for (int numRow = 0; numRow < row+1; numRow ++)
    {
        String string = sc.next();
        for (int numCol = 0; numCol < col+1; numCol++)
        {
            board[row][col] = string.charAt(numCol);   
        }
    }

    sc.close();

    GridGame game = new GridGame (row, col, board);
    game.playGame();
```

An example input text file:

10 10

EEEEEEEEES

SWWWWWWWWW

EEEEEEEEES

SWWWWWWWWW

EEEEEEEEES

SWWWWWWWWW

EEEEEEEEES

SWWWWWWWWW

EEEEEEEEES

TWWWWWWWWW

Comment: Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" Simply dumping the entire (huge) assignment text, and asking a simple question, without showing any code, is not it. We're not going to read through that wall of text to isolate the small part that is relevant to your question. If you want our *free* help, you need to distill the text down to the *relevant* parts, so you can make the question *specific* to what you're asking. Then show the code you do have, to help point out what is troubling you.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I fixed my question :)

Comment: I still have no idea what you're asking about. Do you just need to input a 2d array of Strings? What is "T" (maybe treasure)? Where do north, south, east, and west come into this? Do you have an example of your input file, perhaps three lines of it.

Comment: I adjusted the initial question!

Comment: You didn't say, but I'm assuming you start at array[0][0], follow the direction there, and repeat until you find the "T".  In your example, you should traverse the entire array.  You used a double for loop to create the array.  Use a double for loop to get elements of the array.

Comment: So I would do something like:

for(_____________________)
{
for(_____________________)
{

}
}

Comment: Post the content of the text file as text, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because a Java `array` has 0-based index i.e. the index of the first element is `0` and that of the last element is `array.length - 1`. Therefore, your loop with the variable as the index of the `array` should not go beyond `array.length - 1`. Your terminating condition, `numRow < row+1` is taking the value of `numRow` up to the length of the `array` instead of `array.length - 1`.

Replace

```
for (int numRow = 0; numRow < row+1; numRow ++)
{
    String string = sc.next();
    for (int numCol = 0; numCol < col+1; numCol++)
    {
        board[row][col] = string.charAt(numCol);   
    }
}
```

with

```
for (int r = 0; r < row && sc.hasNextLine(); r++) {
    board[r] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

The other concept you need to understand is a 2-D array in Java an array of arrays i.e. `board[0]` should hold the array of characters from the first line of the file, `board[1]` should hold the array of characters from the second line of the file and so on. Now, if you want to access the 4th character of the 3rd line from the file, you can access it as `board[2][3]`.

The last but not the least is regarding closing the `Scanner` for `System.in`. You should never close this `Scanner` because it also closes the `System.in`. So, you should remove the line, `input.close()` from your code.

## Update

You can write the above mentioned single loop as a nested loop as well but it is unnecessary.

```
for (int r = 0; r < row && sc.hasNextLine(); r++) {
    char[] lineChars = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for(int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
        board[r][c] = lineChars [c];
    }
}
```

You need a nested loop in order to access/process individual characters but to store/access/process each row of a 2-D array, you do not need a nested loop. As I have already mentioned, a 2-D array is an array of 1-D arrays and therefore to access each of these 1-D arrays (not individual elements inside these 1-D arrays), you need a single loop, not a nested loop.

Comment: So since i am required to have a 2D array wouldn't i need to use a nested for loop? And I am required to close the second scanner.

Comment: If you wish, you can do so. However, using a nested loop in this case (i.e. just for storing the characters into `board[][]`) is unnecessary. Using a nested loop is required when you want to process each individual element of a 2-D array but here you want to store the whole rows of character arrays. Feel free to comment if you want me to write a syntax for storing the data into `board[][]` using a nested loop as well.

Comment: That would be nice thank you. Just because later on we will need to access individual characters of the 2D array.

Comment: Hold on...I will do that just for your satisfaction but you can still access individual characters of `board[][]` without any problem. I've already explained that above. I want you to understand the concept instead of just jumping to using a nested loop. You need to use a nested loop in order to access/process individual characters but to store/access/process each row to a 2-D array, you do not need a nested loop.

Comment: I guess what im confused with, is how you are able to declaring the array as a 2D array, but you are only utilizing it as a 1D array. then later calling it as a 2D array? Wouldn't that give an error?

Comment: I understand your confusion now. Think of a 2-D array as an array of 1-D arrays. Now, if I ask you to access each of these 1-D arrays (not individual elements inside these 1-D arrays), do you need a nested loop or just a single loop?

Comment: No you wouldn't  if you were just accessing the 1D array

Comment: Cool...I've updated my answer. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Thats great. Thank you very much for your help!